# How does (twitter) bootstrap place css in the minify file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap, I am just testing it out. Lets say I place CSS code in bootstrap.css it doesnt seem to place it in bootstrap.min.css

Am I missing something!?

Comment: you need to minified it manually. Look for "yui css minifier"

Comment: Don't place things in bootstrap.css

Comment: Those are two separate files. The `.min` version is a verbatim copy of `bootstrap.css` that has been minified. You want to use one or the other, but not both. If you plan on adding to the file, you should not use the minified version.

Comment: Minified CSS files are just CSS files places into one big line for the sake of loading time. Browsers can read minified files quicker than a normal file. The bootstrap file is split into 2 separate files so that you as the reader can understand the normal file. And the computer can still have the minified version. Just link the minified file onto your web page. And use the other file as a reference if you need to check what the CSS is doing.

Comment: I was placing things in bootstrap.css do I need to put them in bootstrap-theme.css?

Comment: @BenAnderson Neither. Make a new CSS file for your changes

Comment: Do I need to do anything so the system minifys the styles?

Comment: You don't NEED to minify yours. The bootstrap library is huge. So having the minified version allows you to just the link the entire library without worrying so much about the weight of it as such.

Comment: I see! Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

They are 2 different files that why. Bootstrap.min.css is just a minified version of Bootstrap.css. This means all the whitespace and other extra characters have been removed, this is normally done to improve loading times. https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources

If you want to add your own styles, just make a new .css file and include it in your project then add all your custom styles in there. You don't need to edit bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: How would the system know to minify your styles if you create a seprate stylesheet?

Comment: Minification is optional, and in your case, probably a micro-optimization. Don't worry about it.